# Admob Banner Ad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

My Xamarin based Android app has several pages. I am using Banner ads in grids at the bottom most row. 
On some pages I have configured the ad to be standard sized banner, on some smart banner and one medium rectangle. 
After releasing the app, the ad is showing only on the standard sized banner.
What could be the reason for it? Does it mean that the Ad creators didn't create smart Ads and also no medium rectangle sized Ads in my vicinity?

Answer (score 0):

You can check :

1. if your adUnitId is correct for the smart banner ad which isn't loading.
2. Smart Banners are ad units that will render screen-wide banner ads on any screen size across different devices in either orientation. Does your ad view fit the screen width ?

Does it mean that the Ad creators didn't create smart Ads and also no medium rectangle sized Ads in my vicinity?

No, When an image ad won't take up the entire allotted space for the banner, it'll center the image and use a hexagonal textile filler (see example below) to fill up the remaining space.

[image]

[Google Support for admob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275335?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I rechecked, the adUnitId is correct.
I am using the following command in the xaml
<local1:AdBanner x:Name="MyAd" Size="SmartBannerPortrait" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="5"/>
And all rows are gridStar.

Comment: If AdMob implementation is working with  your test ad, the implementation should be fine.
Also for fresh AdMob accounts it may take some time to delivery the first ad in release mode.